# Zeckendorf Representation of positive integer

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, mathematics, fibonacci-sequence

Zeckendorf's theorem states that all positive integers can be represented uniquely as the sum of one or more distinct Fibonacci numbers in such a way that the sum does not include any two consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

So given the input 10, the Zeckendorf set would be [8,2].

This is my working code that was for [Reddit's dailyprogrammer challenge](https://redd.it/55zdxx):

```
def fib_list(max_num):
    x=3     #starting at 3 because we have [1,1] in list already.
    list_of_fib = [1,1]
    while x < max_num:
        x = list_of_fib[-1] + list_of_fib[-2]
        list_of_fib.append(x)
    return list_of_fib
    
def find_num_smaller(num, my_list):
    for value in reversed(my_list):
        if value <= num:
            return value 
    
def solve(num):
    combo_list = []
    list_to_pick_from = fib_list(num)
    while num > 0:
        temp_value = find_num_smaller(num,list_to_pick_from)
        num -= temp_value
        combo_list.append(temp_value)
    print(combo_list)

    
solve(10)
```

Running it through `timeit.timeit` I get about 0.069 seconds with the input of `1234`. Medium size input of `123456789` yields about 0.22 seconds and a large size input of `123456789123456789123456789` yields 1.3 seconds. Is there any way to speed it up? Or make it more acceptable at a "higher standard"  (whatever this means, I guess some would call it 'Pythonic' but I'm not sure the correct term)? Maybe there is there some better practice I can employ here.

I have thought of turning `Solve()` into a generator and just getting all the combo values out, but I'm not sure if that's faster.

I know that if I were to run it multiple times, I would check if the input is within the already generated `fib_list`, and if it isn't I would generate a new one. But that's another question, I just want to see one input.

Answer (score 4):

Let's continue from Graipher's code, sans documentation for brevity:

```
def fib(max_num):
    n_1, n = 0, 1
    while n < max_num:
        yield n
        n_1, n = n, n + n_1

def find_num_smaller(num, my_list):
    for value in reversed(my_list):
        if value <= num:
            return value

def solve(num):
    l = list(fib(num))
    while num > 0:
        temp_value = find_num_smaller(num, l)
        num -= temp_value
        yield temp_value
```

What's the slowest part here? `solve` consists of

```
l = list(fib(num))
while num > 0:
    temp_value = find_num_smaller(num, l)
    num -= temp_value
    yield temp_value
```

`l = list(fib(num))` is slow, but only runs once. `num -= temp_value` and `yield temp_value` are relatively quick, and run once per iteration. `find_num_smaller(num, l)`, however, can take a long time *and* runs once per iteration.

This is because we're doing [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html):

> Shlemiel gets a job as a street painter, painting the dotted lines down the middle of the road. On the first day he takes a can of paint out to the road and finishes 300 yards of the road. "That's pretty good!" says his boss, "you're a fast worker!" and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel only gets 150 yards done. "Well, that's not nearly as good as yesterday, but you're still a fast worker. 150 yards is respectable," and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel paints 30 yards of the road. "Only 30!" shouts his boss. "That's unacceptable! On the first day you did ten times that much work! What's going on?"
>
> "I can't help it," says Shlemiel. "Every day I get farther and farther away from the paint can!"

There are some quick fixes. Firstly, we can try binary search. Python has a fast implementation in the `bisect` library. But even better is to "move" the paint can as we go along:

```
while my_list[-1] > num:
    my_list.pop()
return my_list[-1]
```

This can only do as many `pop`s as there are elements in `my_list`, so all the calls added together can't be much slower than generating the list in the first place. The resulting code is *much* faster; for `n = 10 ** 5000` it went from 2.6s to 0.026s, a 100x improvement.

There's also a bug! `fib_list` should be `while x <= max_num`; else `solve(some_fibonacci_number)` will include two consecutive numbers (eg. `solve(5) → 3, 2` instead of `5`).

---

There are some other minor style points:

`temp_value`, `solve` and `my_list` are terrible names, and `fib_list` and `find_num_smaller` are poor. Most variables are temporary, so `temp_variable` tells you nothing in a lot of space. `solve` could refer to solving any problem. `my_list` is silly - obviously it's "your" list and you don't even care if it's a list - you just want a sequence.

There are other improvements, too. Instead of `fib` giving a bounded iterator, produce an unbounded iterator and call `take_while`.

If `find_num_smaller` took a reversed iterator directly, it could be

```
def find_num_smaller(num, nums):
    for value in nums:
        if value <= num:
            return value
```

since iterators automatically "pop" read values. You can even inline this by iterating over a filter:

```
def solve(num):
    fibs = list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= num, gen_fibs()))
    next_fibs = (x for x in reversed(fibs) if x <= num)

    for next_fib in next_fibs:
        num -= next_fib
        yield next_fib
```

which then suggests inlining the loop:

```
def solve(num):
    fibs = list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= num, gen_fibs()))

    for fib in reversed(fibs):
        if fib <= num:
            num -= fib
            yield fib
```

Then one might wonder if you can run `fibs` in reverse, and avoid generating a list. Yes, you can:

```
while True:
    yield next
    prior, next = next - prior, prior
```

So all you need to do is skip forward and iterate backwards:

```
def gen_fibs_reverse(limit):
    prior, next = 0, 1

    while next <= limit:
        prior, next = next, next + prior

    while prior:
        yield prior
        prior, next = next - prior, prior

def zeckendorf_decomposition(num):
    fibs = gen_fibs_reverse(num)

    for fib in fibs:
        if fib <= num:
            num -= fib
            yield fib
```

Answer (score 3):

First some general review:

1. You should use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard around the test run to allow importing of your code from another module.
2. You should add `docstrings` to your functions to explain what they do. Docstrings are of the format:

```
def f(x, y):
    """Returns the sum of `x` and `y`"""
    return x + y
```

---

As you already mentioned, here is a way to use generators. This has two draw-backs compared to your code:

1. In `find_num_smaller` we have to iterate forwards (you cannot iterate backwards through an iterator, at least not without converting it to a list first).
2. We need to re-generate the generator every loop, because it will be partially exhausted

```
def fib(max_num):
    """
    Yields the fibonacci sequence until the last element smaller than `max_num`
    """
    n_1, n = 0, 1
    while n < max_num:
        yield n
        n_1, n = n, n + n_1


def find_num_smaller(num, my_list):
    """
    Iterates through an iterator until the value in the iterator is larger than `num`. 
    Returns the value before that.
    """
    last_value = next(my_list)
    for value in my_list:
        if value > num:
            return last_value
        last_value = value
    return last_value


def solve(num):
    """
    Description here
    """
    x = num
    while x > 0:
        temp_value = find_num_smaller(x, fib(num))
        x -= temp_value
        yield temp_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print list(solve(10))
```

Note that your `fund_num_smaller` will return `None` if all values in `my_list` are smaller than `num`. Here I added returning the last element in that case.

However, this actually performs worse than your code (mostly because iterating reversed saves a lot of time and re-doing the fibonacci sequence wastes a lot of cycles).

As an alternative consider this code:

```
def find_num_smaller(num, my_list):
    for value in reversed(my_list):
        if value <= num:
            return value


def solve(num):
    l = list(fib(num))
    while num > 0:
        temp_value = find_num_smaller(num, l)
        num -= temp_value
        yield temp_value
```

Where I used your `find_num_smaller` and put the fibonacci into a list.

Here is acomparison between the three approaches for the input `123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789` on my machine:

```
no generator     406 function calls in 0.000 seconds
only generators  10111 function calls in 0.003 seconds
mixed            407 function calls in 0.000 seconds
```

So using generators here will not give you a speed improvement for most inputs. For the fibonacci numbers it will, however, give you a memory improvement (which will take quite some time to matter).

For really large inputs (like `123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789`) there is no improvement visible:

```
no generator  2947 function calls in 0.017 seconds
mixed         2948 function calls in 0.017 seconds
```

And for the input `123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789`:

```
no generator  5886 function calls in 0.063 seconds
mixed         5887 function calls in 0.064 seconds
```

So both approaches seem to scale with the number of digits of the input.

Comment: Generators are usually lazy evaluation so they scale way better. I'm not worry about memory because I don't expect someone to input max(int) value into it, Given that if that were to happen, Generators and your method would beat out mine by a long shot. Food for thoughts, but thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @MooingRawr No, here it doesn't, apparently. The `no generator` in the timings is your code. Both seem to scale with the number of digits of the input (I tried twice the length of the number in the second timing and both timings just doubled).

Comment: What helps here is that the fibonacci numbers grow *really* fast.

Comment: right. I forgot to factor in that It's growth is rapid, interesting... Thanks for pointing that out.